# Use label value to create an URL

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a grid, in that grid we have some links to another page depending on the value clicked. But we want to send another parameter on the url (a constant value that is displayed in the upper part of the page). But I cant seem to be doing it right.

Let me attach the part we are using.

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='candidato.aspx?key=<%#Eval("Key")%>?vacIn='HERE WE TRY TO USE THE CONSTANT ID></asp:Label>'>
                     <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
                     <%# Eval("MiddleName") %>
                     <%# Eval("LastName") %>
                     <%# Eval("SecondLastName") %></a>
                    <br />
                    <small><%# GetLabels(Eval("Id").ToString())%></small>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

And we are trying to send the id, that we use in this section, it is already displayed correctly.

```
<tr >
    <td style="width:20%;">
        ID
    </td>
    <td style="width:80%;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: first of all, change second question mark to ampersand like this: candidato.aspx?key=<%#Eval("Key")%>&vacIn='HERE WE TRY TO USE THE CONSTANT ID></asp:Label>'>

Comment: You are absolutely right, I should change it to "&" but how do I call the constant?

<a href='candidato.aspx?key=<%#Eval("Key")%>&vacIn=<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>'>

???

Comment: vacIn=<%#=Idvariable%>

Comment: Sorry if I am being a complete noob, but should I use the label ID vacIn=<%lblID%> or should I use a variable I create in the aspx.cs? like I create a variable, I assign the vacIn and use it like &vacIn=<%#idVac%>'>?

Comment: Yes create a variable.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: Created the variable in the backend code (String idVac = v.Id.ToString();) and tried to called it in <a href='candidato.aspx?key=<%#Eval("Key")%>&vacIn=<%#idVac%>'> but I get the error that the variable does not exist in the right context....

Comment: Make the string public.  Use equals sign in your markup <%=idVac%>

Comment: Got it, needed to make it a public String. Thank You!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137782/discussion-between-trevorbrooks-and-enrique-bravo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a public property in the code behind and reference that in the aspx markup.

Comment: Any time if I can help!